# Typescript: How to return a specific type from class properties with Map/Record type values?

Tags: typescript, class, dictionary, generics, record

I have the following class `DataStore` with two properties of Map types. I am trying to come up with a method `getEntity` that will return proper data type based on parameter. Also trying to create a method `updateEntity` for updating the properties.

```
type TUUID = string;

interface IUser {
    name: string;
    type: 'customer' | 'client';
}

interface IProduct {
    name: string;
    count: number;
    type: 'electronics' | 'food' | 'drinks';
}

const _user: IUser = { name: 'John Doe', type: 'customer' };

interface IDataStore {
    users: Map<TUUID, IUser>;
    products: Map<TUUID, IProduct>;
}

export class DataStore implements IDataStore {
    users: IDataStore['users'] = new Map();
    products: IDataStore['products'] = new Map();

    getEntity<T extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: T, id: TUUID) {
        if (this[storeKey] && this[storeKey].has(id)) return this[storeKey].get(id);
        return null;
    }

    updateEntity<T extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: T, id: TUUID, data: ReturnType<IDataStore[T]['get']>) {
        if (this[storeKey]) {
            this[storeKey].set(id, data);
            return this[storeKey].get(id);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

const store = new DataStore();
const user = store.getEntity('users', '1234');
const product = store.getEntity('products', 'abcd');
const updatedUser = store.updateEntity('users', '1234', _user);
```

But typescript infer data type for `getEntity` as `IUser | IProduct | null | undefined`. When trying to access `product.count`, it provides the following error:

```
Property 'count' does not exist on type 'IUser | IProduct'.
  Property 'count' does not exist on type 'IUser'.
```

Also, this line `this[storeKey].set(id, data);` provides the error:

```
(parameter) data: IUser | IProduct | undefined
Argument of type 'IUser | IProduct | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  The intersection 'IUser & IProduct' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

If I do method overloading, it mostly works. But then the method parameters inside the method become `any` and that is error prone. I tried with Record and just pure objects, still have the same issue. However, if I also do methods for specific property like `getUser`, `getProduct`, `updateUser` and `updateProduct` it does infer the correct type.

Is there any way to have a generic method that will properly infer the data type?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnKaVm) meet your needs?  I had to refactor the types a bit to make the compiler see the correlation, and widen the (implicitly generic) `this` type to `IDataStore`.  Note that the test `if (this[storeKey])` is not useful or necessary if `DataStore implements IDataStore` is true; `DataStore` definitely has those properties, they are not optional.  If that works for you I can write up an explanation; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz this definitely works! I'm kinda surprised as I tried this approach but without the `const thiz: IDataStore = this;`. I'm not sure why it is necessary, could you please explain a bit?

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order for `this[storeKey].set(id, data)` to work you need to refactor the types of `this` and `data` in order for the compiler to see them as obviously compatible with each other.  The general problem of something like `this[storeKey].set()` and `data` having correlated [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), and the fix as implemented and described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) is to refactor to *distributive object types*.

For example, here's a way to rewrite `IDataStore`:

```
interface DataMap {
  users: IUser;
  products: IProduct;
}

type IDataStore = { [K in keyof DataMap]: Map<TUUID, DataMap[K]> }
```

This *looks* like a no-op, and indeed if you inspect `IDataStore`, it looks the same as before:

```
/*type IDataStore = {
    users: Map<TUUID, IUser>;
    products: Map<TUUID, IProduct>;
}*/
```

But the important thing here is that the compiler knows that `IDataStore` acts generically over `K extends keyof DataMap` in a way that it does not know for your original definition.  In `updateEntity` we also change the type of `data` to `DataMap[K]` instead of `ReturnType<IDataStore[K]['get']>`.  The former is seen as related to the `IDataStore` definition for generic `K`, while the latter is too complicated and uses [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) which is implemented as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html).

So here's what we have so far:

```
getEntity<K extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: K, id: TUUID) {
  return this[storeKey].get(id) ?? null;
} // returns IUser | IProduct | null

updateEntity<K extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: K, id: TUUID, data: DataMap[K]) {
  this[storeKey].set(id, data); // error! Argument of type 
  // 'IUser | IProduct' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'
  return data;
}
```

(Note that I removed your presence/absence test, since your properties are not optional).  This isn't obviously an improvement; the output type of `getEntity()` is still a union, and the `set()` method still complains about the intersection.  The problem *now* is that the type of `this` is the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) and it treated by the compiler like an implicit [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter.  It automatically represents the type of the implementing subclass.  This confuses the compiler and it cannot see the connection to `IDataStore`.  The compiler views `this[storeKey]` as a union type because it just widens `this` to its `DataStore` class constraint.  We want to work in terms of `IDataStore` which is specifically built to maintain the correlation.

My approach here is to safely widen `this` to `IDataStore` before accessing the `storeKey` property:

```
getEntity<K extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: K, id: TUUID) {
  const thiz: IDataStore = this;
  return thiz[storeKey].get(id) ?? null;
} // returns NonNullable<DataMap[K]> | null

updateEntity<K extends keyof IDataStore>(storeKey: K, id: TUUID, data: DataMap[K]) {
  const thiz: IDataStore = this;
  thiz[storeKey].set(id, data); // okay
}
```

Now everything works.  The type of `thiz[storeKey]` is now represented in terms of the generic `K` type parameter, so that `get()` returns `DataMap[K] | undefined` and `set()` accepts a `DataMap[K]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=16&pln=16&pc=20#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgqnAkgESgXigZ2AJwJYB2A5gNwBQZhwEOAZgIYDG0icmNUA3mVFAfQFsIALiy5CpHlFCRRAckYBXbAHshOOVAA+UBQBs8EAsDnkAvhSo0GzKIgAKOFQBNFjYFyn8ho7PmLkvIwqisaiBIoCAEY0gdLgIroQehDuTgR4jJiaOnK0Ki45us7+ANbZ5hTBBNhQAPrKNKKs7DjoXHyCiXIAUioAFgRQyCoQcgA08bK6SqrqmmbklMbWTNDI9MD0ALL0YJ68jTiYzWyxUmBOru4ndo4ubsCVZDIsG1sAysAqONAYnFAANoAaSghCgpQgIBUtGGmx2ewAuqJdmAADzwJDISbvBFgEGIgB8UAsZAA9AAqV52XFfH5-A68KBHW6otF+CSTFo0QlxXiXB43FF7dniYhc+7XYC8shmClkigQAAeYB+HkYenomEwcM+31+YIEYBSQmMOpQ8LpBu4h1atwtevpgLkLLkiPaBAgAHcoKiABQASjiAql9tp+ogzpDj2y7ownp9-qDFF4RAgwAAosY8KA0aDldQCM4dZDobCHfQrRBCX7VL9gVDRMDJnhnKJMSgA4ygioah5gP08AAvZrh+ntAd4TB8qC-YCKHBDSdDwF1iANkCIgB0aeAftbXYA-Ie+Io9Ho4mYoGSyVAAHK9u9nzVRFJo3GognEnQRc8p5lgM4mwQFmwA5iAeZQAWRjFhCUIwjSloRjWa4bk2LZtrACAoJMQFbKIH57ASXY2ky1S1Muo5IeOGCTtOUi8Muq4Rhu27sHura4fCQbXreKilPQIBSFespVL2tRrh63q6pWEaBuQ5EeEc7Rrju6ageBfounaEy6AAjAATAAzAALHIyaKVA0buCpEZqZm2agFp1nANkkxyPQUSMM45kKeJSmAcBzhnG0GCqYogXUBpTnaTQbn6cZZmTA0rTJkAA)

Comment: Understood. Thanks a lot for such detailed explanation and helping me out to gain some in-depth knowledge. I hope this question will also help other devs having similar issue.